# Finding an analytic form of a function that satisfies asymptotic conditions

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, special-functions

I have a family of functions that I obtain numerically. They depend on $x$ and parametrically also upon a certain parameter $L$. I would like to find an analytical form for this family of functions so that I can fit certain parameters to the numerical data and obtain the (best) analytical form of $f(x;L)$. These functions are only defined within the interval $x = 0$ to $x = \frac{L}{2}$. I know certain exact properties of my functions:

1. As $x \rightarrow 0$, $f(x;L) \rightarrow \frac{A(L)}{x}$.
2. As $x \rightarrow \frac{L}{2}$, $\partial_x f(x;L) \rightarrow 0$.
3. In between $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{L}{2}$ the functions should decay exponentially, as $B(L) \, e^{-\frac{x}{C(L)}} + D(L)$.
4. $f(x;L)$ and its derivative $\partial_x f(x;L)$ must be continuous within the interval $x \in (0, \frac{L}{2})$.

I have tried with different combinations of exponentials and so on, but I'm stuck finding a suitable form. The numerical data look like this:

[image]

I am looking for help in finding the explicit dependence of $f$ upon $x$ after which I can use the data to find numerical (possibly polynomial) fits for the dependence of $A, B, C$ and $D$ upon $L$.

I apologize in advance for bad terminology etc., it's been a while since my last formal lessons in mathematics!

Comment: Obviously, the data come from some simulation. I think it could be good you explain how is obtained $f(x)$ for a given $x$. May be you could add this information in the post. Please, do not start thinking about polynomial !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The simulation is for the electrostatic potential of a cubic lattice of charged particles in a jellium neutralizing charged background. The polynomials are not for the curves but for the $A(L)$ etc.

Comment: I understood that the polynomials are for $A(L),\cdots$; what I was trying to mean is that physical phenomena are rarely represented by polynomials. I don't know anything about this problem. Does it exist an approximate model ?

Comment: I am not aware of an approximate model for this - finding one is actually part of my motivation here.